# create laravel passport token

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

i want to create controller that will act same like the laravel passport /oauth/token controller.
how can i do that? (i want to send all the parameters that i send to the oauth/token and check them).

i know that i can create a token like that:

```
User::find('1')->createToken('token')->accessToken;
```

but i want to set the oauth_client and check all of this:

```
grant_type
grant_type
client_secret
username
password
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To create and sign your own tokens you can extend Passport's Token class and add a `convertToJWT` method. Here is an example of how to build your own tokens:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Laravel\Passport\Passport;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Builder;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Key;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Rsa\Sha256;
use League\OAuth2\Server\CryptKey;

class CustomToken extends \Laravel\Passport\Token
{
    /**
     * Generate a JWT from the access token
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function convertToJWT()
    {
        $privateKey = new CryptKey(
            'file://' . Passport::keyPath('oauth-private.key'),
            null,
            false
        );

        return (string) (new Builder())
            ->setAudience($this->client_id)
            ->setId($this->id, true)
            ->setIssuedAt(time())
            ->setNotBefore(time())
            ->setExpiration($this->expires_at->getTimestamp())
            ->setSubject($this->user->id)
            ->set('scopes', [])
            ->sign(new Sha256(), new Key($privateKey->getKeyPath(), $privateKey->getPassPhrase()))
            ->getToken();
    }
}
```

You can then create new tokens by calling the constructors with the attributes you require. `Token` inherits from `Model` so the constructor takes an `$attributes` array where the keys should match the column names from `oauth_access_tokens`. Once you've created that token you use the `convertToJWT()` method and return the token in the response:

```php
public function myControllerFunction(Request $request) {
  $token = new CustomToken([...]);
  $access_token = $token->convertToJWT();
  return json(["access_token" => $access_token]);
}
```